# How to sync Google calendar without client IDs and secrets?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, oauth, google-api

I need to sync Google calendar with my Asp.NET MVC 5 application. I have a calendar in my application which is similar to Google's calendar, when I checked the Google documentation where they describes a sample console application. In that application, we need to download a client secret file and which can be used with the application for fetching the data from Google calendar. I can do this in a test environment, but in a production environment its difficult because the client need to download the file himself. How is it possible to get the details of the calendar without any file downloads but with a google login.

I think the clients will be reluctant to download a file and do the processing, how can I forward with syncing the calendar with out any client IDs and secrets.
I know OAuth is there to setup an authentication, but is that possible to forward with out downloading a client secret file ?

Comment: Have you gotten any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data from outh2 with out client permission and use your client-id and client secrete(Client for the API ) then fetch the client user details using the interface.use a library managing the authentication flow. 
Refer Google API Client Libraries.

You have tried the sample console application right, try to use your credentials and to fetch client details. 
Hopes it helps you.

Comment: Thanks.....I don't have much reputation to up vote this answer, I'll do it when I have enough.

Comment: When I try using the API for web application, I have just got the list of events from the Google calendar. When I try to insert it says I don't have permission.

Comment: Have you tried with logic explained in below link. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

Comment: @VinuthaN I have checked your link and I suppose the demo within your link reference still requires Client Id and Client Secret.